# Jenkins How to find if a given slave is running a Job

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins

I have this unique requirement to check if the given node is running a job or not. I am thinking of using groovy as it looks easiest option.

I have found this answer to be useful.

[How can I check via a script or a plugin in Jenkins whether a slave is online before starting a build from another project on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761479/how-can-i-check-via-a-script-or-a-plugin-in-jenkins-whether-a-slave-is-online-be)

It allows me to find if the slave is online or not. Next step for me is to check if it is running a job.

I was considering using the [API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/slaves/SlaveComputer.html) function [setAcceptingTasks(false)](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/slaves/SlaveComputer.html#setAcceptingTasks%28boolean%29) to mark slave as running a Job so that when next time I query using [isAcceptingTasks()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/slaves/SlaveComputer.html#isAcceptingTasks%28%29), I get false and hence do not launch job on that slave.

But I would rather have the slave mark itself.

[taskAccepted()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/slaves/SlaveComputer.html#taskAccepted%28hudson.model.Executor,%20hudson.model.Queue.Task%29) and [taskCompleted()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/slaves/SlaveComputer.html#taskCompleted%28hudson.model.Executor,%20hudson.model.Queue.Task,%20long%29) come to mind.  <strike>I can call the setAcceptingTasks to false once task is accepted and on completion of tasks set isAcceptingTasks to true once again.</strike>

But I am not sure of the arguments these functions take e.g executor and task. And where do these function calls fit in a groovy script.

I am not sure if my assumption of task is equivalent to a job is true or not.

This is what I have got till now:

```
import hudson.model.*
def requiredNodes = ['Slave1', 'Slave2', 'Slave3'];
def status = 0;
for (node in requiredNodes) 
{
      println "Searching for $node";
      slave = Hudson.instance.slaves.find({it.name == node});
      if (slave != null)
       {
        computer = slave.getComputer();
        if (computer.isOffline())
         {
           println "Error! $node is offline.";
           status = 1;
         }
         else 
         {
           println "OK: $node is online";
           if(computer.isAcceptingTasks())
           {
              //Launch job
           }
         }
       }
       else 
       {
         println "Slave $node not found!";
         status = 1;
       }
}
status;
```

EDIT: Number of executors on each slave is 1.

Comment: Not clear why it's a unique requirement to check if a node is running a build. That's exactly what Jenkins master is doing by default. Is your requirement that you do not want to run a build unless N slaves are all currently free?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the hackish way I was able to do it. I changed my workflow to find the available free slave rather than finding if a slave was busy and then checking the next one to see it is free.

This Groovy script counts the number of busy executors on the Slave. It polls continuously till it finds an online slave with zero number of busy executors. I hate polling and will request knowledgeable members to chip in with suggestions to somehow plug into Jenkins event based notification.

```
import hudson.FilePath
import hudson.model.Node
import hudson.model.Slave
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import groovy.time.*

Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.instance
def jenkinsNodes =jenkins.nodes
while(1)
{
    for (Node node in jenkinsNodes) 
    {
        sleep(1000)
        // Make sure slave is online
        if (!node.getComputer().isOffline()) 
        {           
            //Make sure that the slave busy executor number is 0.
            if(node.getComputer().countBusy()==0)
            {
                println "'$node.nodeName' can take jobs !!!"
                return 0
            }
            else
            {
                println "$node.nodeName' is busy !!!"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            println "'$node.nodeName' is offline !!!" 
        }
    }
    sleep(1000)
}
```

This runs as job and returns as soon as it finds a suitable slave. Return 0 is a success in Jenkins.

I am open to better ways of doing it. I am not really happy with this continuous polling I have to do.

Comment: You probably want to use labels, not node names. As you've written this, your solution wont scale once you add another node to do DIFFERENT work.

Comment: there is a span between not busy and not beeing able to take more jobs.
say 2 of 4 job slots can be occupied...

Answer (score 4):

Let me propose a very simple and efficient way

Each node stores the information related to if it example : idle or not , offline or not etc

You can get those details using below command

```
curl -X GET --silent -u jenkins_user:${jenkins_pwd} "http://your_jenkins_url:8080/computer/node_name/api/json"
```

or directly from browser

```
http://your_jenkins_url:8080/computer/node_name/api/jso
```

This result provides valuable information related to slave.

If you want narrow down the search to a specific thing like , is the slave idle or not then you can append it with below logic

```
curl -X GET --silent -u jenkins_user:${jenkins_pwd} "http://jenkins_domanin:8080/computer/node_name/api/json" | python -c 'import json,sys,os;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["idle"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the node, that is running the current build, just use System.getenv("NODE_NAME")

> When a Jenkins job executes, it sets some environment variables..

You may find these variables very useful. Check [this link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables)