# Jenkins Workflow Optional Node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

We have a section of our pipeline that needs to be run on slaves running windows so we have a section similar to:

```
node("Windows") {
   // Do some windows stuff
}
```

Because this part of the pipeline isn't mission critical I'd prefer the whole job not to fail if the Windows slaves are down for some reason.

Is there some way of having some logic here that says "do this if a Windows slave is up but skip if there all down".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question gave me the information I needed.

[Jenkins How to find if a given slave is running a Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142674/jenkins-how-to-find-if-a-given-slave-is-running-a-job)

So I was able to use:

```
node.getComputer().isOffline()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Conditional Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin. So you can wrap you windows part of workflow script into slave validation of some sort.