# Getting Slave node details using python jenkins api

Tags: python, jenkins

I am aware that there is a python jenkins api. But i don't know how to get the slave node details.
I need to know if the slave node is offline or nor. Number of busy executors and some other stuffs.
In groovy we can get the details like this, [Jenkins How to find if a given slave is running a Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142674/jenkins-how-to-find-if-a-given-slave-is-running-a-job/27242903)

```
node.getComputer().isOffline()
node.getComputer().countBusy()
```

How to do this in python. How to get all individual node details.
Where to find the detailed documentation.
Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look [here](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html?highlight=node%20)

Comment: Yeah i tried this before itself . I am getting, AttributeError: 'Jenkins' object has no attribute 'get_node_info'

Comment: can you share the detailed code thats throwing the error